# Bash OR operator

Tags: bash

My script is working with this:

```
if pgrep -f "/home/tiger/bin/pymp" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
```

I want it to check for mpv2 also.

This is what I have so far:

```
if [[ /usr/bin/pgrep -f "/home/tiger/bin/pymp" ]] || [[ /usr/bin/pgrep -f "/usr/bin/mpv2" ]] >/dev/null 2>&1; then
```

These are the errors I'm seeing:

/home/tiger/bin/pauseMusic.sh: line 3: conditional binary operator expected
/home/tiger/bin/pauseMusic.sh: line 3: syntax error near `-f'
/home/tiger/bin/pauseMusic.sh: line 3:`if [[ /usr/bin/pgrep -f "/home/tiger/bin/pymp" ]] || [[ /usr/bin/pgrep -f "/usr/bin/mpv2" ]] >/dev/null 2>&1; then'

Comment: I've edited the post to show the errors I'm seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[[` and `]]` operators are for explicit comparative tests.  If you want to check two *command* results, just use the shell:

```
$ if /usr/bin/pgrep -fq "/home/tiger/bin/pymp" || /usr/bin/pgrep -fq "/usr/bin/mpv2" ; then do_stuff; fi
```

Not all versions of `pgrep` support the `-q` argument to suppress output.  If this is the case for you, you can suppress each `pgrep` individually or combine the redirection:

```
$ if { /usr/bin/pgrep -f "/home/tiger/bin/pymp" || /usr/bin/pgrep -f "/usr/bin/mpv2";} > /dev/null 2>&1 then do_stuff; fi
```

or

```
$ if /usr/bin/pgrep -f "/home/tiger/bin/pymp" > /dev/null 2>&1 || /usr/bin/pgrep -f "/usr/bin/mpv2" > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then do_stuff; fi
```

Comment: That's giving this error: /home/tiger/bin/pauseMusic.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `||'

Comment: @user57649 Leave out the `>`. Its a leftover from copy. My `pgrep` does not support  the option `-q`.

Comment: There is still the `q` in the last two examples :-).

Comment: ♫ Copypasta my old friend / You show my laziness again... ♫